# MDF, LDF files on a virtual drive

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

**The situation.**
I have one physical drive split into 3 virtual drives.
C: Has SQL Server installed,
D: Has the MDF files,
E: Has the LDF files

**The question**
Because this is all virtual will SQL Server still see the MDF and LDF files as being on one physical drive ?

Thanks

Comment: What you call a "virtual drive" is usually called a partition.

Answer (score 3):

Putting MDF and LDF on different drives (or even splitting the MDF in several files) only makes sense if the drives are really different physical drives.

If they are on the same physical drive (like in your case), you can as well put everything on the same drive, because it makes no difference performance wise.

It also follows logical sense that splitting 1 physical drive into 3 virtual drives adds a virtualization layer that could potentially slow down performance.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server will see the files as being on separate drives, but performance will be severely diminished because of the program, data and log files being on the one physical drive.